# How to `require` parameters to not only to be present, but to be a Hash with String Parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have quite common code in our controller to handle Parameter whitelisting and sanitizing:

```
def create
  @sign_in = SignIn.new(sign_in_params)
  # ...
end

def sign_in_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
end
```

This, however, raises an exception on the following params:

```
{
  "user": "foobar"
}
```

The reason is that `params[:user]` is present, but that it does not return another Hash, but instead a string.

Causing an exception: `NoMethodError: undefined method`permit' for "foorbar":String`.

How can I not only ensure that `require` requires a parameter to be present, but also requires it to be a Hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the strong_parameters documentation it is valid to call the methods multiple times. so you could do it like this:

```
# create a strong-parameter for testing
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({user: {email: "some@email.com"}})
# make sure the key is present, raises ActionController::ParameterMissing otherwise
params.require(:user)
# make sure the structure is as expected and use the result
return params.permit(user: [:email])
```

Comment: Perfect solution! A pity that I lose the concise-ness of the one-liner this way, but it makes sense, and is a small trade-off.